# What is the correct number of constructor parameters? / How could I combine these classes?

Tags: c#, oop

Firstly I have a class signature that looks like this:

```
internal class JobStore : IJobStore
{
    private readonly IFileHandler fileHandler;
    private readonly IJobSerializer serializer;
    private readonly IJobValidator validator;
    internal readonly string DirectoryPath = "JobStore";
    internal readonly string JobExtension = ".job";

    public JobStore(IFileHandler fileHandler, IJobSerializer jobSerializer, IJobValidator jobValidator)...
```

I kind of want to remove the DirectoryPath and extension into their own class, but I'm not too sure.
I do think having four objects in the constructor is a bad idea though.

My question is how could I combine two of these objects to reduce the number of parameters I'm taking into this method, and is three too much?

Apologies for the vagueness of the question.

Comment: Why do you think you should limit your parameters?

Comment: There are 3, not 4, objects in the constructor.  Does it have multiple constructors?

Comment: SRP - I feel like the class with a single responsibility should not be utilising so many classes, this leads me to think three classes + knowing about it's own directory + extension might be a bit much.

Comment: @48klocs there *would* be four, if I added a class for directory path and job extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should [Refactor to Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. I think fileHandler + job serializer go together as they are always used in conjunction?

Comment: This is really excellent advice. Think carefully about what groups of dependencies really go together. Can an IJobSerializer do its work without an IJobValidator? If not, find a way to spin that off into (ex.) an IJobValidatedSerializer.

Comment: Just did it, it worked great, made a saver and a retriever class (the saver included validation, which exists in a class with job serializer).

Answer (score 0):

4 objects in your constructor is not too many.  There is no specific number of parameters that counts as "too many"

Mind you, there are other, more grey criteria for things that you might or might not want to use your constructor for, but the specific parameter count, isn't where your focus should be.

Just make sure that you class represents a noun of some sort, and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

you can have a constructor with multiple parameters and it's ok. In fact, three is a small number of parameters, maybe you will have methods and constructors with n parameters and, as long as you need all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the number of required parameters when you're using it, then perhaps using default parameters could help.

That way, if you find yourself only changing one or two parameters and using defaults all other times, you don't have to pass so many parameters when newing it up.

However, this doesn't take parameters off of the constructor itself.

So, I'm not sure what you're looking for, but perhaps this may help you. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx